# Trouble getting response from hyperledger fabric getStateByRange and getStateByPartialCompositeKey

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

I'm having trouble getting an answer from this methods, no mather what I do I only get the final done object in the iterator with no other objects. I  know for sure there are objects in the blockchain, I can get them using the getState method.

This is my code for the getStateByPartialCompositeKey:

```
public async getStatesByPartialKey(className: string, key: string): Promise<any> {
    const states = [];
    const datas = [];
    const iterator = await this.ctx.stub.getStateByPartialCompositeKey(className, [key]);

    while (true) {
        const data = await iterator.next();
        datas.push(data);

        if (data.value && data.value.value.toString()) {
            const state = State.deserialize(data.value.value, this.supportedClasses);
            states.push(state);
        }
        if (data.done) {
            await iterator.close();
            return datas;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my code for the getStateByRange method:

```
public async getStatesByRange(startKey: string, endKey: string): Promise<any> {
    const states = [];
    const datas = [];
    const iterator = await this.ctx.stub.getStateByRange(startKey, endKey);

    while (true) {
        const data = await iterator.next();
        datas.push(data);

        if (data.value && data.value.value.toString()) {
            const state = State.deserialize(data.value.value, this.supportedClasses);
            states.push(state);
        }
        if (data.done) {
            await iterator.close();
            return datas;
        }
    }
}
```

This is one of the objects I have in the blockchain:

```
{
    "class":"com.example.state",
    "key":"\"COMPANY1\":\"1f5ee25d-546e-46d2-96cd-f7b7a347f84f\"",
    "currentState":1,
    "id":"1f5ee25d-546e-46d2-96cd-f7b7a347f84f",
    "issuer":"COMPANY1"
}
```

This is how I'm using them:

```
getStatesByPartialKey('com.example.state', 'COMPANY1');
getStatesByRange('COMPANY0', 'COMPANYz');
```

This is the only answer I'm getting:

```
[{"done":true}]
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm using "fabric-shim": "^1.2.0".

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The problem I had was creating the keys, I was using the stub.createCompositeKey but it was creating the keys with a u0000 character at the begining of the key and the method stub.getStateByRange couldn't find anything, even when I looked for a range creaded with the stub.createCompositeKey method.

I had to change the way I create the keys and then I started to find my records.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem. I was using createCompsiteKey too, and getSateByRange wasn't returning anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try my below code snippet

```
let startKey = 'COMPANY0';
let endKey = 'COMPANYz';

// empty string for start and end keys returns full state
let iterator = await stub.getStateByRange(startKey, endKey);

let allResults = [];
while (true) {
  let res = await iterator.next();

  if (res.value && res.value.value.toString()) {
    let jsonRes = {};
    console.log(res.value.value.toString('utf8'));

    jsonRes.Key = res.value.key;
    try {
      jsonRes.Record = JSON.parse(res.value.value.toString('utf8'));
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      jsonRes.Record = res.value.value.toString('utf8');
    }

    allResults.push(jsonRes);
  }
  if (res.done) {
    console.log('end of data');
    await iterator.close();
    console.info(allResults);
    return Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(allResults));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In previous versions of Fabric, `getStateByRange` API used to return composite keys even when doing a range query on simple keys. For example, the following range query on marble02 chaincode example returned both simple keys such as `marble2`, `marble3`, and composite keys such as `color~namebluemarble2`, `color~namebluemarble2` where it should have returned only `marble2` and `marble3`.

`$ peer chaincode query -n mycc1 -v 0 -c {"Args":["getMarblesByRange","a","z"]} -o 127.0.0.1:7050 -C ch1`

Query Result:

```
[
    {"Key":"color~namebluemarble3", "Record":}
    {"Key":"color~nameredmarble2", "Record":}

    {"Key":"marble2", "Record": 
        {"docType":"marble","name":"marble2","color":"red","size":50,"owner":"tom"}
    },
    {"Key":"marble3", "Record": 
        {"docType":"marble","name":"marble3","color":"blue","size":70,"owner":"tom"}
    }
]
```

There was no way for Fabric to differentiate between a simple or composite so that `GetStateByRange()` could return only simple keys.

Composite keys have an objectType prefix. Each part of composite key is delimited by null character for example `chaincodeid 0x00 objectType 0x00 ck1 0x00 ck2 0x00`. This design ensured that various composite key types have an objectType namespace to guarantee no collisions across types. You can check this yourself by hovering over *copy* icon on any CouchDB record which have a composite key like in the image below.
[image: couchdb-composite-key]

Now, `getStateByRange()` returns only simple keys and `getStateByPartialCompositeKey()` returns only composite keys. The namespaces for simple keys and composite keys are different to avoid collisions. For more information on this, you can refer to this [thread](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-2183), where Fabric maintainers had a discussion on how to approach this issue.

If you do an unbounded range query on start & end, you won't see any composite key in the results. I tried it myself and these were the results that I received.

`peer chaincode query -n marbles -C mychannel -c '{"Args":["getMarblesByRange", "", ""]}'`

Output:

```
[
    {"Key":"azurite","Record": 
        {"color":"yellow","docType":"marble","name":"azurite","owner":"john","size":2}
    },
    {"Key":"marble1","Record": 
        {"color":"red","docType":"marble","name":"marble1","owner":"tom","size":50}
    },
    {"Key":"marble2","Record": 
        {"color":"blue","docType":"marble","name":"marble2","owner":"tom","size":70}
    }
]
```

However, when I kept `\u0000` as my start key, I received records that had composite key as well.

`peer chaincode query -n marbles4 -C mychannel -c '{"Args":["getMarblesByRange", "\u0000", ""]}'`

Output:

```
[
    {"Key":"\u0000color~name\u0000blue\u0000marble2\u0000","Record":"\u0000"}, 
    {"Key":"\u0000color~name\u0000red\u0000marble1\u0000","Record":"\u0000"}, 
    {"Key":"\u0000color~name\u0000yellow\u0000azurite\u0000","Record":"\u0000"}, 
    {"Key":"azurite","Record": 
        {"color":"yellow","docType":"marble","name":"basil","owner":"john","size":2}
    },
    {"Key":"marble1","Record": 
        {"color":"red","docType":"marble","name":"marble1","owner":"tom","size":50}
    },
    {"Key":"marble2","Record": 
        {"color":"blue","docType":"marble","name":"marble2","owner":"tom","size":70}
    }
]
```

So, in conclusion, `getStateByRange` API shouldn't be used to fetch records that have composite keys, but `getStateByPartialCompositeKey`.