# Trouble getting response from hyperledger fabric getStateByRange

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

Im using `createCompsiteKey`, and `getSateByRange` only returns `{"done":true}`.
I tried to replace `createCompsiteKey` with concat key part to make the key as follows.
`getSateByRange` only returns `{"done":true}`,  I'm using "fabric-shim" v1.4.0 and "fabric-contract-api" v1.4.0. "fabric-peer" image is 1.4.6.

Code for `addState` to db is below:

```js
class StateList {
    async addState(state){
    let keyParts = state.getSplitKey();
    let keyPrefix = (String)(keyParts.slice(0,1));
    let keyOthers = keyParts.slice(1);
    
    /*. comment createCompositeKey
    let key = this.ctx.stub.createCompositeKey(keyPrefix, keyOthers);
    */
    let key = keyParts.map(part => part).join('');

    let data = State.serialize(state);
    await this.ctx.stub.putState(key, data);
   }
}

class State {
    constructor(stateClass, keyParts) {
        this.class = stateClass;
        this.key = State.makeKey(keyParts);
    }
    static makeKey(keyParts) {
        return keyParts.map(part => part).join(':');
    }
    static splitKey(key){
        return key.split(':');
    }
}

async getDevCollectByRange(ctx, startKey, endKey){
    let args = [];
    args[0] = startKey;
    args[1] = endKey;
    let xiotdatadevlist = await ctx.xiotDataDevList.getDevByRange(args);
    return Buffer.from(xiotdatadevlist);
}

async getAllResults(iterator){
    let allResults = [];
        while (true) {
        const res = await iterator.next();

        if (res.value && res.value.value.toString()) {
            console.log(res.value.value.toString('utf8'));

            const Key = res.value.key;
            let Record;
            try {
                Record = JSON.parse(res.value.value.toString('utf8'));
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
                Record = res.value.value.toString('utf8');
            }
            allResults.push({ Key, Record });
        }
        if (res.done) {
            await iterator.close();
            return allResults;
        }
    }       
}

async getObjectsByRange(args) {

    if (args.length < 2) {
        throw new Error('Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting 2');
    }
    // date 
    const startKey = args[0];
    const endKey = args[1];
    
    const resultsIterator = await this.ctx.stub.getStateByRange(startKey, endKey);
    let results = await this.getAllResults(resultsIterator, false);

    return Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(results));
}
```

If I use `createCompsiteKey`, how can `getSateByRange` find my records?
Or what condition fabric key must meet?

any suggestion, Thank you.

Comment: Unable to understand your question. Please narrow the problem and remove code lines which are not helping in describing your question.

Comment: sorry. my problem is same to the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57806267/trouble-getting-response-from-hyperledger-fabric-getstatebyrange-and-getstatebyp 
but I can not get clear solution

Comment: I plan to comment the post, but I not 50 reputation to comment, so I summit new post

Comment: Your question statement is a little unclear. could you please help me in understanding why aren't you using the method "createCompositeKey"? Why have you commented it out?

Comment: if using createCompositeKey,  for example,
I my code: Suppose keyParts is [XIOT, BATCH, 1,20200708123059], keyPrefix = XIOT, keyOthers=BATCH, 1,20200708123059
then createCompositeKey(keyPrefix, keyOthers) output is XIOT:BATCH:1:20200708123059 
when getSateByRange (startKey = "XIOT:BATCH:1:20200708123059"  , endKey="XIOT:BATCH:1:20200820123059") ,  stub.getStateByRange's response iterator is [91, 93], which is not correct result

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57806267/trouble-getting-response-from-hyperledger-fabric-getstatebyrange-and-getstatebyp
owner of the link not choose to use createCompositeKey, she say " I was using the stub.createCompositeKey but it was creating the keys with a u0000 character at the begining of the key and the method stub.getStateByRange couldn't find anything".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In previous versions of Fabric, `getStateByRange` API used to return composite keys even when doing a range query on simple keys. For example, the following range query on marble02 chaincode example returned both simple keys such as `marble2`, `marble3`, and composite keys such as `color~namebluemarble2`, `color~namebluemarble2` where it should have returned only `marble2` and `marble3`.

`$ peer chaincode query -n mycc1 -v 0 -c {"Args":["getMarblesByRange","a","z"]} -o 127.0.0.1:7050 -C ch1`

Query Result:

```
[
    {"Key":"color~namebluemarble3", "Record":}
    {"Key":"color~nameredmarble2", "Record":},
    {"Key":"marble2", "Record":{"docType":"marble","name":"marble2","color":"red","size":50,"owner":"tom"}},
    {"Key":"marble3", "Record":{"docType":"marble","name":"marble3","color":"blue","size":70,"owner":"tom"}}
]
```

There was no way for Fabric to differentiate between a simple or composite so that `GetStateByRange()` could return only simple keys.

Composite keys have an objectType prefix. Each part of composite key is delimited by null character for example `chaincodeid 0x00 objectType 0x00 ck1 0x00 ck2 0x00`. This design ensured that various composite key types have an objectType namespace to guarantee no collisions across types. You can check this yourself by hovering over *copy* icon on any CouchDB record which have a composite key like in the image below.
[image: couchdb-composite-key]

Now, `getStateByRange()` returns only simple keys and `getStateByPartialCompositeKey()` returns only composite keys. The namespaces for simple keys and composite keys are different to avoid collisions. For more information on this, you can refer to this [thread](https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-2183), where Fabric maintainers had a discussion on how to approach this issue.

If you do an unbounded range query on start & end, you won't see any composite key in the results. I tried it myself and these were the results that I received.

`peer chaincode query -n marbles -C mychannel -c '{"Args":["getMarblesByRange", "", ""]}'`

Output:

```
[
    {"Key":"azurite","Record": 
        {"color":"yellow","docType":"marble","name":"azurite","owner":"john","size":2}
    },
    {"Key":"marble1","Record": 
        {"color":"red","docType":"marble","name":"marble1","owner":"tom","size":50}
    },
    {"Key":"marble2","Record": 
        {"color":"blue","docType":"marble","name":"marble2","owner":"tom","size":70}
    }
]
```

However, when I kept `\u0000` as my start key, I received records that had composite key as well.

`peer chaincode query -n marbles4 -C mychannel -c '{"Args":["getMarblesByRange", "\u0000", ""]}'`

Output:

```
[
    {"Key":"\u0000color~name\u0000blue\u0000marble2\u0000","Record":"\u0000"}, 
    {"Key":"\u0000color~name\u0000red\u0000marble1\u0000","Record":"\u0000"}, 
    {"Key":"\u0000color~name\u0000yellow\u0000azurite\u0000","Record":"\u0000"}, 
    {"Key":"azurite","Record": 
        {"color":"yellow","docType":"marble","name":"basil","owner":"john","size":2}
    },
    {"Key":"marble1","Record": 
        {"color":"red","docType":"marble","name":"marble1","owner":"tom","size":50}
    },
    {"Key":"marble2","Record": 
        {"color":"blue","docType":"marble","name":"marble2","owner":"tom","size":70}
    }
]
```

So, in conclusion, I think you shouldn't use `getStateByRange` API, but `getStateByPartialCompositeKey` to fetch records which have composite keys.

Comment: if using getStateByRange ,I think that simple key add valid prefix to avoid  [getMarblesByRange","a","z"]，which also lead to same aim with CompositeKey.

 getStateByPartialCompositeKey is Partial order query,  which may enlarge query range and need additional work to definite range.  another new getStateByCompositeKeyRange is better.

I need make more test.
Thanks you  Kartik very much.

Comment: Please consider this as the accepted answer if it answers your question. Thank you.

Comment: yeh, it help me much. but I can not add 1 score, when I add 1 socre,
"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: No, I'm asking you to just mark this answer as accepted answer if it answers your question. You can see a checkmark icon just below the upvote/downvote icons. You can click on it to make this answer as the accepted answer.